# What's the simplest way to handle cross-coupled property validation in the UI for a class implementing IDataErrorInfo?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I've just spent quite a bit of time looking into this and have a solution but perhaps someone has a better approach?

Assume I have a model class with two properties and I want to ensure that they are always the same.  When exposing this in the UI, I want the input controls for *both* properties to reflect error-state as text is entered in either of them.  [Needless to say, this is a very simple version of the actual problem I'm trying to solve.]

```
public class DoublyNamedThing : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }

    //IDataErrorInfo implementation
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            return (Name1 == null || (!Name1.Equals(Name2)))
                       ? string.Format("{0} should be the same as {1} and non-null", Name1, Name2)
                       : null;
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }
}
```

I present these through the following XAML (StackPanel is bound to an instance of DoublyNamedThing).

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel.BindingGroup>
      <BindingGroup />
  </StackPanel.BindingGroup>

  <TextBox Name="_name1" Margin="2" TextChanged="ForceRevalidation"
   Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Path=Name1,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>

  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=_name1,Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />

  <TextBox Name="_name2" Margin="2"  TextChanged="ForceRevalidation"
   Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Path=Name2,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>

  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=_name2,Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
</StackPanel
```

The ForceRevalidation event-handler is defined as

```
    private void ForceRevalidation(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = sender as FrameworkElement; //null checks omitted
        foreach (BindingExpressionBase binding in element.BindingGroup.BindingExpressions)
            binding.UpdateTarget();
    }
```

[Enforcing Complex Business Data Rules with WPF by Brian Noyes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714593.aspx) suggests that the event handler is necessary since BindingGroups don't automatically update their elements but I'm wondering if there is any trick that would allow me to get away without it or whether the approach I've taken is flawed in some subtle way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to use it

MyViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    #region Name Properties

    private string _name1;

    public string Name1
    {
        get { return _name1; }
        set { _name1 = value; _firstLoad = false; RaisePropertyChanged("Name1"); }
    }

    private string _name2;

    public string Name2
    {
        get { return _name2; }
        set { _name2 = value; _firstLoad = false; RaisePropertyChanged("Name1"); }
    }

    #endregion

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _name1 = String.Empty;
        _name2 = String.Empty;
        _firstLoad = true;
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool _firstLoad;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var pc = PropertyChanged;
        if (pc != null)
            pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _error = String.Empty;
    public string Error
    {
        get { return _error; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (_firstLoad)
                return String.Empty;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Name1":
                case "Name2":
                    return (Name1 != null && (Name1.Equals(Name2)))
                   ? String.Empty
                   : string.Format("{0} should be the same as {1} and non-null", Name1, Name2);

            }
            return Error;
        }
    }
}
```

My Xaml with containing just one `StackPanel`

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Height="25" Width="150"  Margin="10,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Name1, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
    <TextBox Height="25" Width="150" Margin="10,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Name2, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Xaml code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.DataContext = new MyViewModel ();
    }
}
```

I hope this example helps. At the moment only a red border appears if there is an error

Comment: Thanks aks81. I was aware from Brian's article that one way to force the revalidation is to propagate a change notification for the related properties but this doesn't set well with me. 

This is a model class and making it implement INotifyPropertyChanged just to get around some View behaviour seems wrong.  (None of the properties can change independently of the client requests, it's just the error state for each which may change.)

My preferred mechanism would be to replace the TextChanged event-handler with something like "ForceRevalidationOfBindingGroup=True" in the Binding statement.

Comment: Are you binding the View directly to the Model?